# How show select options by id when I edit then update it?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

```
class Guest extends Model{


public function programs()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Program::class, 'guest_show', 'guest_id', 'program_id')
        ->withPivot('subject', 'show_date');
}
public function specialties()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Specialization::class,'guest_speciality','guest_id','speciality_id');
}




class Program extends Model{
protected $table = 'programs';
protected $primaryKey = 'program_id';

public function guests()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Guest::class,'guest_show','program_id','guest_id')
        ->withPivot('subject', 'show_date');
}}



class Specialization extends Model{
protected $table = 'specialties';
protected $primaryKey = 'specialty_id';

public function guests()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Guest::class,'guest_speciality','speciality_id','guest_id');
}
```

I have tables: `guests,programs,specialties,guest_speciality,guest_show`

I have form from all tables,the form contain select options from programs table and select options from specialites table.

How controller function and views write code of this models?